# Finding index to value in [[String]]

Tags: arrays, swift

Looking for a way to check if an [[String]] array contains a value and then find the index of that value.

The [[String]] array is named: "categoriesArray" and contains three String arrays

Tried using .indexOf like below:

```
var location = categoriesArray.indexOf(array1)
```

But I get an error saying:

Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '([String]) throws -> Bool'

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: What is `roundLightArray`?

Comment: @JosephK. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` or it newer version `index(where:)` takes closure as parameter, not an object you're looking for. Correct usage:

```
// index will return optional Int
var location = categoriesArray.index(where:{$0==roundLightArray})
```